# Find sum of records by user split by month in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I want to retrieve from the database an array of values, one for each month, that is the sum of the users transaction prices.

For example: A user buy three items (1Euro, 2Euro, 3Euro) in March and two items in April(5euro, 10Euro).

I want to return an array containing something like {mar:6,apr:15}

Apologies if the explanation is poor but can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

kSeudo.

Comment: What type is this row in database?

Comment: Its a 'purchases' table that contains rows with item purchase related fields: userId, purchaseDate, purchaseAmount, Details etc.

Its a mysql database

Comment: Ok, but `purchaseAmount` is decimal (or int) and `purchaseDate` is datetime, right?

Comment: Correct, I should have said that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to group by `purchaseDate` and sum up the `purchaseAmounts`:

```
Select Date_Format(purchaseDate, '%M%Y') month, sum(purchaseAmounts)
From purchases
Group by Date_Format(purchaseDate, '%M%Y')
```

If you want the amounts per user and month, include the `userID`:

```
Select UserID, Date_Format(purchaseDate, '%M%Y') month, sum(purchaseAmounts)
From purchases
Group by UserID, Date_Format(purchaseDate, '%M%Y')
```

If you are looking for the purchases from a single user, add `where UserID = That_Users_ID` to the first statement.

Comment: Thanks TPete,

This is almost there but it is not summing the purchaseAmounts, I still get one entry per purchase

If I figure it out I'll post solution.

Comment: @kSeudo You could post your `create table` statement and some sample data. From what you provided so far, this should be right.

Comment: Bingo... there was a typo on my part. Works perfectly, and its so simple. Thanks TPete!